# Folium & Map object has not attribute Marker

Tags: python, folium

While discovering Folium got an AttributeError while trying to add a Marker to a folium map.

```
import folium

map_osm=folium.Map(location=[50.4547,30.5238], zoom_start=6, tiles='Stamen Terrain')
map_osm.Marker(location=[45.463612, 29.294559], popup='Solar Power Station')

map_osm.save('spst.html')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'Marker'
```

Appreciate any help on how to get around this!

Comment: In your case I would go for map_osm.add_children(folium.Marker(location=[45.463612, 29.294559], popup='Solar Power Station')), instead. But this may depend on the Folium version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
folium.Marker([45.463612, 29.294559], popup='Solar Power Station').add_to(map_osm)
```

So your code should look like

```
import folium

map_osm=folium.Map(location=[50.4547,30.5238], zoom_start=6, tiles='Stamen Terrain')
folium.Marker([45.463612, 29.294559], popup='Solar Power Station').add_to(map_osm)

map_osm.save('spst.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an old version of Folium. Try:

```
pip install -U folium
```